# PHP & MYSQL script inside wordpress theme-functions.php to pull & echo data

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have this code in a theme-functions.php file on wordpress, I'm using this script and when needed I'm running a `echo`followed by the string to replicate the data.

currently when I use this I just get 0 results, echo on the $userlogin is working so I know the filter in the mysql select is fine.

```
function calliod() {
    global $wpdb;

$user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
$userlogin = $user->user_login;
echo $userlogin;

$iodoutput = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->iod WHERE wp_iod.USERID ='". $userlogin. "'";
$result1 = $iodoutput;

if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {

$USERID= "" . $row["USERID"]. "";
$CurrentPayment= "" . $row["CurrentPayment"]. "";
$LastMonthPayment= "" . $row["LastMonthPayment"]. "";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
}
```

---

RESOLVED:

Here is the code

Inside Functions.php

```
function calliod(){

global $wpdb;
$user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
$userlogin = $user->user_login;

foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_iod WHERE wp_iod.USERID ='". $userlogin. "'") as $key => $row) {

global $USERID;
$USERID = $row->USERID;
}
}
```

On WP Page

```
<?php 
calliod(); 
echo $GLOBALS['USERID']
; ?>
```

Now i can pull any column from the table mentioned as long as i define it in the first script.

Comment: `$result1 = $iodoutput;`  u need to execute your query here

Comment: Actually what you are looking for?

Comment: basically, from from this script i want to place `echo $CurrentPayment` on a page in wordpress so that the user can see their current billing payment while using the current wordpress database connection rather than making a second connection.

Comment: Without query execution u can't get values

Comment: Replying to your updated code, the issue is now that you're not returning the $CurrentPayment value from the function. You can't just set a value in a function and expect it to be available outside of the function. You have to return that value. So, the last line of your while loop needs to either echo $CurrentPayment or "return $CurrentPayment" so that it can be assigned as a value outside of the function.

Comment: One last thing that may help you understand PHP a bit more.. On your resolved, final code, you're setting a $GLOBAL variable. That's ok and works, but is not great practice. Instead of the global variable stuff at the end of your function just use "return $row->USERID". This makes the calling of the function 'return' a value for your use later. Then, outside of your function, you can just say "echo calliod();".. or to assign it a variable, "$ciod = calliod();". This prevents messy use of global variables and will be very helpful as you learn more about PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query that you're building is never actually executed. See the documentation for the WPDB class, but basically you need a line that says this:

```
$result1 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_iod WHERE wp_iod.USERID ='". $userlogin. "'" );
```

More info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: I've added that into it & still getting 0 results...`$iodoutput = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_iod WHERE wp_iod.USERID ='". $userlogin. "'" );
$result1 = $iodoutput;`

Comment: I'm guessing at your actual database's table name -- I put it as 'wp_iod' in my code. Is that actually the table name you need to query? And does it have a column in it of "USERID"?

Comment: Try just changing the get_results query to "SELECT * FROM wp_iod", and running it again just to make sure that works. If it returns results, then the problem is in the wp_iod.USERID = $userlogin stuff.

Comment: I'd also make sure that the wp_iod.USERID data is actually usernames, and not user ID numbers

Comment: removed the WHERE section there & still 0 Results. (cleared cache too). USERID of this table contains the username which is what im pulling back from the $userlogin. (echo confims correct username displayed) double checked userid in DB & it does contain the username. ..... the script is in the current theme's "theme-functions.php" is that alright? or should it be placed in another location?

Comment: If the "SELECT * FROM wp_iod" doesn't return anything, then it's really tough to say what's going on. That should return SOMETHING, assuming wp_iod has data in it (it does).  Also note that theme-functions.php isn't a file that's automatically loaded by WP's theme loading process. It's possible your theme is loading it specifically, but the typical filename is "functions.php"